# Increase Height of last cell

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I created a table using the *iTextSharp.text.pdf* library.

Table I created:

[image: Table created with iTextSharp.text.pdf library]

Code I used:

```
var signTable = new PdfPTable(2);
signTable.WidthPercentage = 65f;
signTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
signTable.SetWidths(new[] { 25, 40 });

//SignName
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("PDFPackagingSlip.SignName", lang.Id), font));
cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
signTable.AddCell(cell);

//creates empty cell
cell = new PdfPCell();
signTable.AddCell(cell);

//SignDate
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("PDFPackagingSlip.SignDate", lang.Id), font));
cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
signTable.AddCell(cell);

//creates empty cell
cell = new PdfPCell();
signTable.AddCell(cell);

//Signature
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_localizationService.GetResource("PDFPackagingSlip.Signature", lang.Id), font));
cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
signTable.AddCell(cell);

//creates empty cell
cell = new PdfPCell();
signTable.AddCell(cell);

//add table to pdf document. 
doc.Add(signTable);
```

**Question**

How can I increase the height of the last added empty cell?(cell in right bottom corner)

I tried using following code, but it didn't change anything:

```
signTable.Rows[2].SetExtraHeight(5, 80f);
```

Comment: It's ages that I last used ItextSharp, but you could try a margin or better, padding...

Comment: Not really a nice looking solution, but have you tried to add line jumps (`"\n"` or [`Chunk.NEWLINE`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html#NEWLINE)) instead of leaving the cell empty?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon hmm, good idea, I will try this one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
cell.MinimumHeight = 80f;
```

or

```
cell.FixedHeight = 80f;
```